# How to create multiple themes (css) for different clients

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, themes

I need to allow each customer to customize it's own theme.
My Problem is how to know which theme to show before someone logs in.

My Idea is to use a sub-domain for each client.

anyone can point me to a guide for best practice on how to implement this?
I'm using Angular 4 for my client side.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use subdomains you will need to purchase a more expensive ssl certificate, besides, they don't all sell. I hope you are using https?

Comment: Currently I'm using http but in the future will use https.
I don't mind to pay a little more for the ssl certificate, the question is what is the best practice for implementing this?
Is using sub-domains the right approach?

Comment: i dont think so. depends on how deep processing of interface in themes. try to do only css

Comment: still how to know which css to load before the user logs in?
I don't see any other solution then sub-domain.

Comment: why css of the theme to load before login? after all, you don't know that this is the same user.

Answer (score 0):

1) Bad solution (change to css)

```
temporalScriptRender() { 
    setTimeout(() => {
      var s2 = document.createElement("script");
      s2.type = "text/javascript";
      s2.src = "/assets/js/scripts.js";
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s2);
     }, 1000)
}
```

2) Good solution

```
 constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

        FirstTheme() {
            this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'first-theme.css'); }


        SecondTheme() {
            this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'second-theme.css'); }
```